# Looking for a hex editor which can show structure and sections of files automatically, eg. show PE file headers in editor

Tags: hex, editor, portable-executable

I want to see the hex codes of EXE file(PE file), is there a good editor that can show each sections of PE file automatically? Mark each sections clearly, otherwise, I need to count the number of bytes to know the sections of PE file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "PE Explorer" from heaventools, which makes it easy to analyze the structure of PE files.

Answer (score 0):

A good no-nonsense GUI PE viewer that does what you are asking is PEview.  It can be downloaded for free at http://wjradburn.com/software/

The left pane contains a TreeView that breaks down the sections of a PE file.  When you click on a section entry, the right pane fills with a hex view of that section.  You can also see the header byte interpretations and their file offsets by clicking on any of the header breakdowns.  The strength of this tool is its simplicity.

I'd also like to add that I am not the author of this tool.